# ubuntu 14 hibernate does not appear clear to me

Tags: hibernate

i am recently come from windows 7 to ubuntu 14 
how can the PC hibernate in ubuntu system ?

i tried a command but it doesn't work will
thanks

Comment: To test if your system will hibernate properly, open a terminal and enter the command

Answer (score 0):

To test if your system will hibernate properly, open a terminal and enter the command

`sudo pm-hibernate`

If the system properly turns off, and comes back on with out problems, then you can follow the [instructions here](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/04/enable-hibernate-ubuntu-14-04/) to enable hibernation on your system.